# Integrate Google Hangouts on Air with your website like webinarjam

Tags: google-hangouts

I'm having a hard time finding the right information, but we are working on a project where users would be able to create/schedule live webinars that would run off Google's Hangout On Air.

A user would be on our website and schedule the webinar which would create a hangout on air with google and send back the youtube link so it could be embedded into the users page on our website. Now I know how to embed a single hangout, but you have to run through googles interface to set it up.

I found a company called webinarjam that actually accomplished this, but I cannot figure out how or what API they tapped into. So would you know how to accomplish this or another alternative that would have a simple interface?